# Iterate over Pandas dataframe cells to calculate running totals based on other cell values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate a mass balance through a system in Python.  In my current example, there are about 35,000 daily records, but I want to reuse the code for examples with much greater data.

I have a CSV file that captures daily data for:

- Date
- stream flow
- Rainfall
- Inflows

I want to calculate new columns of data that look to both the previous and following days data.  For example, I want to calculate additional columns that represent:

- Bypass - the portion of INFLOWS that bypass the facility (ie are greater than a Treatment Capacity) to the Wet Weather Pond
- Recirculating Flow - If current INFLOWS are less than the Treatment capacity and the pump flows from the Wet Weather pond back to the facility for retreatment if the pond volume>0
- Irrigation - If rainfall in previous 3 days <10mm AND no rainfall is in following 5 days, irrigate a set volume
- PondVolume - Previous pond volume + bypass - recirculating flow-irrigation

I am new to Python and thought I would utilize Pandas for this data, as I could keep all of the data together. I used np.where for simple conditional calculations using cells on the same row.

```
bal['Q_IL2TR'] = np.where(bal['Q_PS2IL']<FullTreatementFloMLDs, bal['Q_PS2IL'], FullTreatementFloMLDs)
```

Is it possible to iterate through a dataframe, and create new column values based on cells in columns from previous/following rows?  Also is the best approach to the problem.

Comment: Would be great if you show us the few initial lines of DataSet that really helps to reproduce and answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Do not start by trying to iterate through a DataFrame.  That's very slow.  Instead, try to do everything in terms of vectors.

By the way, this:

```
bal['Q_IL2TR'] = np.where(bal['Q_PS2IL']<FullTreatementFloMLDs, bal['Q_PS2IL'], FullTreatementFloMLDs)
```

Should be more simply written as:

```
bal['Q_IL2TR'] = bal['Q_PS2IL'].clip(upper=FullTreatementFloMLDs)
```

As for things like this:

> Irrigation - If rainfall in previous 3 days <10mm AND no rainfall is in following 5 days, irrigate a set volume

You can create rolling sums with window size 3 and 5, store those as new columns in your DataFrame, then use them to create a condition:

```
last3 = df.Rain.rolling(3, closed=False).sum() # n.b. you might want 4
next5 = df.Rain.rolling(5, closed=False).sum()
df['Irrigate'] = (last3 < 10) & (next5 == 0)
```

Comment: @ John .. nice answer indeed :) +1 , However it's better to provide the Dataset by OP that helps to another seeking same  over SO to understand.

Comment: Thanks John, that answer solves most of my problems.  If the data is known before doing a calculation, the creating a new shifted column is the preferred way.

Comment: However, if the data is known before doing a calculation, the creating a new shifted column is the preferred way. However, if the value is based on a calculation I dont think this approach works.  I clarified my question to make this clearer, I hope, of what I am trying to achieve.  In my example, the Recirculating Flow occurs when the Wet Weather Storage is > 0, the Inflows are less than Treatment Capacity, and the value is the difference between Treatment Capacity less current Inflow.  Thanks for your assistance and also the better code.

Comment: To complete the answer to my question, I would use John's method where possible, but to iterate over the solution I would use the following:

Comment: for i in range(1, len(bal)):          #iterate from second row to length of dataframe
    j = df.columns.get_loc('bal')
    if df.A[i] >= df.A[i-1]:
        df.iat[i, j] = 99     #or some other formula
    else:
        df.iat[i, j] = 0       #or some other formula